# Crashes on fresh 22.04.1-Ubuntu

Tags: crash

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 22, and I am experiencing random craashes while playing games.  I have run memtest and disk checks, and they are all fine.  Below are two crash logs, and all the system informations.  I have looked online but I can't find anything that helps.  Thank you!

Here's the last two crash logs (from trying to play 0ad and flightgear):

```
Jul 04 10:09:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/modern/sprites.xml: 1.57323 ms
Jul 04 10:09:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/global.xml: 339.539 us
Jul 04 10:09:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/setup.xml: 300.666 us
Jul 04 10:09:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/sprites.xml: 547.442 us
Jul 04 10:09:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/styles.xml: 64.079 us
Jul 04 10:09:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| loading/styles.xml: 43.462 us
Jul 04 10:09:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| loading/sprites.xml: 229.305 us
Jul 04 10:09:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| loading/loading.xml: 15.3302 ms
Jul 04 10:09:22 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[948]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Jul 04 10:09:22 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[948]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Jul 04 10:09:26 manu-OptiPlex-9010 pkexec[2790]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
Jul 04 10:09:26 manu-OptiPlex-9010 pkexec[2790]: manu: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/manu] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-system->
Jul 04 10:09:26 manu-OptiPlex-9010 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[1212]: unable to update icon for software-update-available
Jul 04 10:09:26 manu-OptiPlex-9010 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com[1212]: unable to update icon for livepatch
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/modern/setup.xml: 108.421 us
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/modern/styles.xml: 86.057 us
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/modern/sprites.xml: 1.11743 ms
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/resources/: 240.445 us
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/global.xml: 246.764 us
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/setup.xml: 188.873 us
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/sprites.xml: 377.116 us
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/styles.xml: 41.428 us
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| session/setup.xml: 47.046 us
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| session/sprites.xml: 930.392 us
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| session/styles.xml: 93.8 us
Jul 04 10:09:29 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| session/session.xml: 98.8981 ms
Jul 04 10:09:31 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: GAME STARTED, ALL INIT COMPLETE
Jul 04 10:09:42 manu-OptiPlex-9010 PackageKit[1496]: search-file transaction /119_dcddeced from uid 1000 finished with success after 29999ms
Jul 04 10:09:43 manu-OptiPlex-9010 PackageKit[1496]: search-file transaction /120_beaaacba from uid 1000 finished with success after 322ms
Jul 04 10:09:43 manu-OptiPlex-9010 PackageKit[1496]: get-details transaction /121_acccbdab from uid 1000 finished with success after 269ms
Jul 04 10:10:05 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/modern/setup.xml: 215.278 us
Jul 04 10:10:05 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/modern/styles.xml: 188.325 us
Jul 04 10:10:05 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/modern/sprites.xml: 2.63026 ms
Jul 04 10:10:05 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/global.xml: 488.399 us
Jul 04 10:10:05 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| common/sprites.xml: 824.766 us
Jul 04 10:10:06 manu-OptiPlex-9010 0ad_0ad.desktop[2045]: TIMER| options/options.xml: 46.4935 ms
Jul 04 10:10:09 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jul 04 10:10:09 manu-OptiPlex-9010 anacron[2818]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2023-07-04
Jul 04 10:10:09 manu-OptiPlex-9010 anacron[2818]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jul 04 10:10:09 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: anacron.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 04 10:10:22 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[948]: Started Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
Jul 04 10:12:19 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
Jul 04 10:12:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 04 10:12:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: Finished Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
Jul 04 10:12:50 manu-OptiPlex-9010 dbus-daemon[699]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.s>
Jul 04 10:12:50 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
Jul 04 10:12:50 manu-OptiPlex-9010 dbus-daemon[699]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Jul 04 10:12:50 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Jul 04 10:13:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: systemd-timedated.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 04 10:15:47 manu-OptiPlex-9010 kernel: radeon 0000:01:00.0: ring 3 stalled for more than 10240msec

And

Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property hydro/pitch-tweak-factor is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/c172p-hydrodynamics.xml: line >
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property hydro/yaw-tweak-factor is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/c172p-hydrodynamics.xml: line >
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property hydro/yaw-stability-tweak-factor is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/c172p-hydrodynamics.xml: line >
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property hydro/fbx-lbs is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/c172p-hydrodynamics.xml: line >
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property hydro/fby-lbs is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: 
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: 
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: 
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: 
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: 
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: 
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/c172p-heat.xml: line 22
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property heat/human-body-temp-degc is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/indicated-airspeed.xml: line 45
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property /instrumentation/airspeed-indicator/indicated-speed-kt is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/mooring-jsbsim.xml: line 81
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property mooring/mooring-connected is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/mooring-jsbsim.xml: line 84
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property mooring/latitude-deg is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/mooring-jsbsim.xml: line 85
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property mooring/longitude-deg is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/mooring-jsbsim.xml: line 86
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property mooring/altitude-ft is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/mooring-jsbsim.xml: line 89
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property mooring/rope-spring-coeff-lbs_ft is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/mooring-jsbsim.xml: line 90
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property mooring/max-rope-force-lbs is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]: In file /usr/share/games/flightgear/Aircraft/c172p/Systems/mooring-jsbsim.xml: line 91
Jul 04 10:23:12 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:       Property mooring/rope-length-ft is already defined.
Jul 04 10:23:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:   157.77 [ALRT]:flight     Failed to save initial FDM property state
Jul 04 10:23:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:   157.96 [ALRT]:io         mipmapping: texture size not a power-of-two: /usr/share/games/>
Jul 04 10:23:24 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:   162.75 [INFO]:nasal      Starter on
Jul 04 10:23:27 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:   165.20 [INFO]:nasal      Hobbs system started
Jul 04 10:23:31 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:   168.79 [INFO]:nasal      Starter off
Jul 04 10:23:36 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:   173.77 [INFO]:nasal      Primer reset to 0
Jul 04 10:23:52 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:   189.78 [ALRT]:nasal      ERROR: Cannot add listener to tied property /controls[0]/light>
Jul 04 10:23:55 manu-OptiPlex-9010 org.flightgear.FlightGear.desktop[2040]:   193.14 [ALRT]:nasal      ERROR: Cannot add listener to tied property /controls[0]/anti->
Jul 04 10:24:20 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: Starting Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
Jul 04 10:24:21 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jul 04 10:24:21 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: Finished Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
Jul 04 10:24:50 manu-OptiPlex-9010 dbus-daemon[705]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.s>
Jul 04 10:24:50 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: Starting Time & Date Service...
Jul 04 10:24:50 manu-OptiPlex-9010 dbus-daemon[705]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.timedate1'
Jul 04 10:24:50 manu-OptiPlex-9010 systemd[1]: Started Time & Date Service.
Jul 04 10:24:53 manu-OptiPlex-9010 gnome-shell[1217]: libinput error: event3  - DELL Dell USB Entry Keyboard: client bug: event processing lagging behind by 36ms, yo>

manu@manu-OptiPlex-9010:~$ uname -a
Linux manu-OptiPlex-9010 5.19.0-46-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 21 15:35:31 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
manu@manu-OptiPlex-9010:~$ sudo lshw
manu-optiplex-9010          
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: OptiPlex 9010 (OptiPlex 9010)
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    version: 01
    serial: 6LT9BY1
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=desktop sku=OptiPlex 9010 uuid=4c4c4544-004c-5410-8039-b6c04f425931
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0W2F8G
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A01
       serial: /6LT9BY1/CN7220037901FE/
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: A14
          date: 06/11/2013
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 12MiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 5c
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.58.9
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 2849MHz
          capacity: 3900MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cpuid_fault epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 microcode=33 threads=8
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 38
             slot: CPU Internal L1
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: internal write-through data
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 39
             slot: CPU Internal L2
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: internal write-through unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 3a
             slot: CPU Internal L3
             size: 8MiB
             capacity: 8MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 3b
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: M378B5173QH0-CK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial: 9567A653
             slot: DIMM3
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: M378B5173QH0-CK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 1
             serial: 9567A658
             slot: DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: M378B5173QH0-CK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 2
             serial: 9567A654
             slot: DIMM4
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
             product: M378B5173QH0-CK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 3
             serial: 9567A659
             slot: DIMM2
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=ivb_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 09
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f7e00000-f7efffff ioport:e0000000(size=268435456)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: Turks PRO [Radeon HD 7570]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: /dev/fb0
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
                configuration: depth=32 driver=radeon latency=0 resolution=1920,1200
                resources: irq:32 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7e20000-f7e3ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:c0000-dffff
           *-multimedia
                description: Audio device
                product: Turks HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500/6600 / 6700M Series]
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
                logical name: card1
                logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
                logical name: /dev/snd/hwC1D0
                logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D3p
                version: 00
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
                resources: irq:31 memory:f7e40000-f7e43fff
              *-input
                   product: HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                   physical id: 0
                   logical name: input7
                   logical name: /dev/input/event4
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:26 memory:f7f20000-f7f2ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-46-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-communication:0
             description: Communication controller
             product: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:f7f3c000-f7f3c00f
        *-communication:1
             description: Serial controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.3
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm msi 16550 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=serial latency=0
             resources: irq:19 ioport:f0a0(size=8) memory:f7f3a000-f7f3afff
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: eno1
             version: 04
             serial: b8:ca:3a:ac:00:e2
             size: 1Gbit/s
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.19.0-46-generic duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=10.0.0.237 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
             resources: irq:28 memory:f7f00000-f7f1ffff memory:f7f39000-f7f39fff ioport:f040(size=32)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7f38000-f7f383ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.19.0-46-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.19
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
```